# Is there a performance penalty using await/async?

Tags: c#, performance, async-await

I'm considering rewriting my network library with await/async paradigm. Lots of code which uses the library is still synchronous, so I'm planning on moving the entire library into the async mode and then creating method stubs, which would transform the async calls into synchronous calls.

Can anyone suggest to me whether this is going to make my library worse for synchronous use? (like if it would consume more cpu, method calls would take longer to execute etc)?

Comment: Please elaborate, are you going to leave your library synchronous and just add async wrappers around it?

Comment: “creating method stubs, which would transform the async calls into synchronous calls” [You shouldn't do that.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx)

Comment: Good material available at https://www.dynatrace.com/blog/behind-net-4-5-async-scene-performance-impact-asynchronous-programming-c/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will definitely not be faster, synchronous code can respond to incoming data quicker.

The advantage you get from doing it asynchronously is that your library will scale a lot better, being able to handle many more connections.  A side effect of not having hundreds of threads doing nothing but waiting for data to arrive.  The disadvantage of doing it asynchronously is that your library will be much harder to use by the client app.  Which is what async/await solves.  There is no benefit if you make it synchronous again yourself, it must be left to the client app.

Comment: just curious: why does synchronous be able to respond quicker? Is that mainly because the overhead of async/await patterns? I thought this was relatively small.

Comment: The thread that is waiting for the I/O completion is guaranteed to be ready to run.  Not necessarily the case in async code, there is no thread, especially so when the continuation runs on the UI thread.  The OS thread scheduler also boosts their priority and is highly likely to pick the waiting thread.  Async usually works fine because the I/O operation is already so slow (network latency most typically, milliseconds) so the extra activation delay is impossible to notice.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant ! Quite interesting - so much depth in coding.

Answer (score 4):

The proper answer here is to benchmark it, try rewriting a couple of methods with async and see how they perform when used synchronously.

Having said that [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx) explains that yes there is a cost to setting up the state required for async methods and so only use them if it's beneficial. For a network library (where the vast majority of your time is probably spent waiting for the network) the time cost for setting up async is probably negligible.

In summary, for a network library it's probably fine, but benchmarking is the **only** way to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Only perfomance penalty is that async/await is using state machine. So perfomance influence is such as yield return instead of returning an array/list.